# Azure WebJob Console Application Empty Args when calling from webhook

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, asp.net-webhooks

I'm working on Azure WebJob. 
I started by creating a console application in Visual Studio and I published the application as a webJob in portal.azure from VisualStudio.

the WebJob is Triggered Manualy from its Webhook with `username` and `password` `https://{MyWebAPP}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{MyWebJob}/run?arguments=1 2 3` from a second program.

this WebJob is verry simple. It only displays a the arguments 1,2 and 3.

when I run the program from CommandeLine like so `dotnet MyProject.dll 
1 2 3` it works well.
but  when I run it from webHook it does not read arguments.

here is my main script :

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("PARAMS Passed : " + string.Join(",", args));
    }
}
```

This is the log in the WebJob when I run from WebHook by Post request : `[06/09/2018 15:19:37 > 33a9f2: INFO] PARAMS Passed :`

and this is the console when I run it from commande Line : `[06/09/2018 15:19:37 > 33a9f2: INFO] PARAMS Passed : 1,2,3`

Can some One Help PLEASE. 
Tha,ks From All.

Comment: Does your Webjob folder contain run.cmd file? Have you tried reading WEBJOBS_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS?

Comment: @JanneP You're on the right track as it relates to `run.cmd`. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This comes down to a VS publishing bug. The problem is that it auto-generates a `run.cmd` that has:

```
dotnet foo.dll
```

When it really should have:

```
dotnet foo.dll %*
```

So that the arguments get flowed into your console app.

I'll report the issue, but for now you can work around as follows:

- Explicitly create a `run.cmd` at the root of your console app (i.e. next to program.cs). Make it contain the correct line above with `%*`. And obviously, use your actual dll name instead of foo.dll :)
- Add it to your project, and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` (default is Do not copy).

That will cause your `run.cmd` to get deployed, and VS won't auto-generate the faulty one.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. I Was dying you are a god. Thanks a lot Mrs David